# How do I CAST a date in a subquery? Currently getting an error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called `Source` in my table called `TPR`. The `Source` column is of datatype `varchar` and contains text like `January 2020` and `Q3 Completed`. When I run a query that only extracts the date-like fields to `CAST` as dates like so:

```
SELECT CAST(Source AS DATE) AS Source
FROM TPR
WHERE Source NOT LIKE 'Q3 Completed`
```

I get the appropriate results. When I place the query above in a subquery to act as a filter like so:

```
SELECT CaseNumber
FROM TPR
WHERE Source =
     SELECT CAST(Source AS DATE) AS Source
     FROM TPR
     WHERE Source NOT LIKE 'Q3 Completed`
```

I get the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

I've also tried the following but it too failed:

```
SELECT CaseNumber
FROM TPR
WHERE CAST(Source AS DATE) =
     SELECT CAST(Source AS DATE) AS Source
     FROM TPR
     WHERE Source NOT LIKE 'Q3 Completed`
```

I don't understand why this is failing.

Comment: Subqueries go in parenthesis. `= (SELECT CAST(Source AS date) FROM ...)` so the above wouldn't even generate that error. Though the error is also telling you the problem; you have a value you can't convert to a `date`. So the *real* problem is your storing your date (and time) value in a non date and time data type; you need to fix that.

Comment: I hope table TPR isn't a table of reports' data........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `try_cast()`:

```
SELECT CaseNumber
FROM TPR
WHERE Source = (SELECT TRY_CAST(Source AS DATE) AS Source
                FROM TPR
                WHERE Source NOT LIKE 'Q3 Completed'
               );
```

The issue is that some rows in `TPR` do not have valid dates in `Source`.  So, the conversion *can* fail -- depending on the execution plan.  The two queries have different execution plans, and one is trying to convert rows that don't meet the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: So, `try_cast` did work. I think it's correct but I have to check some more. 

Isn't `WHERE` one of the first clauses to be executed? https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution If so, why wouldn't the WHERE in the subquery be executed first?

Comment: And what happens if `try_cast` doesn't work on a particular record, will remove it from the record results?

Comment: @AxSQLQuestions . . . It returns `NULL` if the conversion fails.  Given the logic of the query, the value will be filtered out.